# Django UpdateView form with multiplechoicefield going to form in_valid when posted without selecting the multiple choice field?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a update view for my model and this model has a many to many relation with another model. Due to some filtering requirements I created a custom multiplechoicefield and am saving it by modifying the form_valid. But if this multiple choice field is not selected form is getting posted to form_invalid. This field is not required. My view and form look as follows:

```
class Updatemodel(UpdateView):
    template_name = ...

    def get_success_url(self):
        return .. 

    def get_from_class(self):
        .. ..

    def form_valid(self,form):
        kwargs = super(Updatemodel, self).get_form_kwargs()
        m2m_initial = kwargs['instance'].model_m2m.filter( .. )
        chosen_m2m = model_m2m.objects.filter(pk__in = form.cleaned_data.get('model_m2m'))
        m2m_add = chosen_m2m.exclude(pk__in = m2m_initial.values_list('pk, flat = True))
        m2m_remove = m2m_initial.exclude(pk__in = chosen_m2m.values_list('pk,flat = True))
        form.instance.model_m2m.add(*m2m_add)
        form.instance.model_m2m.remove(*m2m_remove)

        return super(Updatemodel, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
         kwargs = super(Updatemodel, self).get_form_kwargs()
         kwargs['m2m_initial'] = kwargs['instance'].model_m2m.filter( ..)
         kwargs['m2m'] = model_m2m.objects.all().filter( .. )
```

.................. form ......................

```
class m2m_update_form(forms.ModelForm):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          m2m = kwargs.pop('m2m',None)
          m2m_initial = kwargs.pop('m2m_initial',None)

          super(m2m_update_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          choices = [(M2M.pk, M2M.Name) for M2M in m2m ]
          self.fields['m2m_field'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = choices, widget = FilteredSelectMultiple("M2M", False, choices = choices))
          self.initial['m2m_field'] = [M2M for M2M in m2m_initial]

      class Media:
          ..

      class Meta:
          model = model1
          fields = ['field1', 'field2','field3']
          widgets = {
            'field3' = FilteredSelectMultiple("Field", False),
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this solve your problem?

```
self.fields['m2m_field'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = choices, 
                               widget = FilteredSelectMultiple("M2M", False, choices = choices), 
                               required=False)
```